# Trying to call method name using string: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method

Tags: javascript

So, I've figured out how to call a method in JavaScript when you have the method name in a string e.g. `strCallback = 'targetMethod'; window[strCallback]();`, however, I get the following error message indicating that it can't find the method and *after researching* I'm still not sure why.

Calling the method by the actual name works, but not by using `window[strCallback]();`

Error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'targetMethod'`

Code:

```
function startMethod(strCallback) {
    var results = '...';
    // window[strCallback](results); // <-- Causes error
    targetMethod(results); // <-- Works
}

function targetMethod(r) {
    console.debug(r);
}

startMethod('targetMethod');
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It looks like the method `targetMethod` is not a global method that is why you are getting the error message.

If you have declared it as a closure method then you cannot access it using this method

Comment: Can you share the some more context to the code? like whether these functions are declared within another function etc

Comment: Sorry I'm new to javascript -- thanks for the downvote! -- the code above is the exact code minus the filler for getting results via an ajax call.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter and really I don't have an idea why it is downvoted

Comment: Can you provide the entire script block, because it really does not look like the method is declared in the global scope, to test this change the `targetMethod` declaration to `window['targetMethod'] = function(r){console.debug(r);}` and see

Comment: I've added the entire code, as I said it works fine if I call it by function name, but window[functionNameInString] fails.

Comment: If you call it by name it works because then the call is happening from one context, but if you use `window[name]` then the function will be searched only the global context where it does not seems to be existing

Comment: You're right, this fixed the issue: `window['populateBrandSelectList'] = function (results) {`

Comment: why do you want to pass the function name as a string rather than a function reference, because what I gave was not a solution it was a workaround

Comment: As a solution I would recommend passing the callback as a function reference and I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion in comments it looks like the problem is the context in which the callback method is declared. If you use `window[callback]` it expects the callback to me declared in the global context, in your case it does not appear to be the case. It might be because you have declared everything inside a anonymous function/dom ready creating a closure context for the function.

As a solution I would recommend not to pass the callback as a function name string, instead pass it as a function reference.

So instead of calling `startMethod('targetMethod');`, you need to call `startMethod(targetMethod);` and invoke callback using `strCallback()` instead of `window[strCallback](results);`.

I solution we worked out in the comments was just a workaround where we forced the callback to the global scope which is not a recommended method

Comment: Thanks, that's even better